# Media Foundation: How to Decode Compressed AVI?

Tags: codec, avi, ms-media-foundation, video-codecs, vfw

folks!

I'm trying to transcode a compressed .avi file to .wmv using Media Foundation. While I've succeeded in using MSDN's [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for transcoding to handle an uncompressed .avi, I've had no luck with several different types of compressed .avi (Windows Video 1 is one example of compression).

Does anyone have experience with this? I have had little luck searching, other than MSDN (which does not clearly handle this particular case).

One route I'm leaning toward is writing a custom Media Foundation Transform to decode using Video For Windows internally, but it seems like I -must- be reinventing the wheel. A sample of something similar can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Please tell me I'm foolish and show me what I'm missing! Thanks. :)

Comment: Stock MF transforms neither cover formats/decoders of earlier APIs, nor wrap VFW/DShow decoders. So you will need to reinvent the wheel...